Golfscript whole-stack rotation
There isn't a builtin in golfscript which lets you rotate a bigger portion of the stack than the three top-most elements and I wanted to try to implement one.
I came up with this
]-1%(1$1$1$1$<@@)>+@@=\~]-1%~

But I feel like it can be done with fewer characters

You’re probably going to get better answers over at codegolf.se. You could even turn it into a challenge…
